# wpf treeview binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

Is there any simple tutorial for beginners about **treeview binding in WPF**?

What should we write in ItemsSource, DataType, ItemTemplate attributes if there's
one List of items?

```
IList<string> items = new List<string>();
items.Add("item1");
items.Add("item2");
items.Add("item3");
```

XAML code:

```xml
<TreeView Name="treeView1">  
    <TreeView.Resources> <!-- what does it mean? -->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="???" ItemsSource="{Binding ???}"></HierarchicalDataTemplate>  
    </TreeView.Resources>  
</TreeView>
```

Comment: You should take a step back and try to figure out what each of those things are before trying to bind a TreeView. Just follow a beginners WPF tuturial - there are heaps out there.

Answer (score 34):

To Fully understand how to use the wpf treeview with data binding, I went through the following tutorials in order -

1. A very simple example of treeview binding using recursion

http://testdrivendevelopment.wordpress.com/2008/07/15/databinding-wpf-treeview-using-recursion/

2. Claus Konrads simple example of data binding with the treeview. It's the most straightforward example I have come across and should get any newcomers to wpf up to speed.

[http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2011/04/how-to-make-hierarchical-treeview.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20210306225409/http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2011/04/how-to-make-hierarchical-treeview.html)

3. Mike Hillbergs tutorial shows, in detail, the ins and outs of the treeview, how it compares to other wpf controls, and how to bind data.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx

Comment: Claus Kondrad's example is great.

Comment: The first example needed a couple of tweaks to get working - I got rid of "Path=" in the bindings and added a Window.DataContext entry for local:Service where xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimpleWpfTreeView" for a project called "SimpleWpfTreeView"

Comment: Claus Konrad's blog appears to be unavailable so too is Mike Hillberg's tutorial on MSDN which just defaults to Microsoft Dev Blog front page

Answer (score 13):

The trick is that `ItemsSource` points to the next collection down.

e.g Imagine you have a collection of type A, and each A contains a description and a collection of type B; and each B contains a description and a collection of type C. The binding would look like this:

```
<TreeView Width="400" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfA}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TypeA}" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfB}">
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding TypeADescription}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TypeB}" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfC}">
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding TypeBDescription" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TypeC}">
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding TypeC}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Seeing as TypeC items have no children, you can just use a simple DataTemplate,  rather than a HierarchicalDataTemplate for those items.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at Josh Smiths excellent [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx)

Comment: in this definite example - what shoud I do? in the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Treeview is one control in wpf that you have to appoach in a little diffrent manner.It is simple and efficient and at the same time a pain to understand and get in track for a beginer,especially those coming from the windows appliaction backgroud.Please go through the [MVVM](http://blogs.msdn.com/johngossman/archive/2005/10/08/478683.aspx) pattern first and then try to approach the treeview.

The Josh Smith article below is a good place to start.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx