# ObservableCollection of objects of a certain type and treeview binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, observablecollection

I am trying to bind an ObservableCollection of objects to a TreeView. The object class is shown below

```
public partial class Layer_Properties : Window
{    
    //fields
    private string _routeName;
    private  List<Stop> _Stops_List = new List<Stop>();

    public string routeName   // property
    {
        get { return _routeName; }   // get method
        set { _routeName = value; }  // set method
    }

    public List<Stop> Stops_List   // property
    {
        get { return _Stops_List; }   // get method
        set { _Stops_List = value; }  // set method
    }

    public List<PolylineBarrier> polylineBarriers// property
    {
        get { return _polylineBarriers; }   // get method
        set { _polylineBarriers= value; }  // set method
    }

    public Layer_Properties(RouteTask asolveRouteTask, MapViewModel aMapViewModel)
    {      
        InitializeComponent();
        solveRouteTask = asolveRouteTask;
        _mapViewModel = aMapViewModel;

        this.Loaded += async (o, e) =>
        {
            await Task.Run(() => getnetworkDatasetProprties(solveRouteTask));
            routeGUID = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());
            dateTime_label.IsEnabled = false;
            dateTime_ComboBox.IsEnabled = false;
            this.dateTime_ComboBox.Value = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Use_Time_Windows_chkbox.IsEnabled = false;
            Use_Time_Windows_chkbox.IsEnabled = false;
            Use_Time_Windows_chkbox.IsEnabled = false;
            PreserveFirstStop_chkbox.IsChecked = true;
            PreserveLastStop_chkbox.IsChecked = true;
            PreserveFirstStop_chkbox.IsEnabled = false;
            PreserveLastStop_chkbox.IsEnabled = false;

            Layer_Properties item = null;
            if (_mapViewModel.LayersPool.Count <= 1)
            {
                item = _mapViewModel.LayersPool[_mapViewModel.LayersPool.Count - 1];
            }
            else
            {
                item = _mapViewModel.LayersPool[_mapViewModel.LayersPool.Count - 2];
            }

            if (item != null)
            {
                item.routeName = IndexedFilename("Route", item.routeName);
            }
        };
    }
```

Part of the mapviewmodel is shown below:

```
public class MapViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MapViewModel()
    {
    }

    //test 09062020
    public ObservableCollection<Layer_Properties> LayersPool
    {
        get { return layersPool; }
        set
        {
            layersPool = value;
            NotifiyPropertyChanged("LayersPool");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Layer_Properties> layersPool= new 
    ObservableCollection<Layer_Properties>();

    void NotifiyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (LayersPoolChanged != null)
            LayersPoolChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler LayersPoolChanged;
    //endtest
}
```

Part of the xaml is shown below:

```
<Window x:Class="GIS_App.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:esri="http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/runtime/2013"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GIS_App"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="732" Width="1399" Closing="Window_Closing">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:MapViewModel x:Key="MapViewModel"/>
    <ImageBrush  x:Key="NetworkAnalystWindow" ImageSource="/icons/NetworkAnalystWindow.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    <ImageBrush  x:Key="AddNetworkElement" ImageSource="/icons/AddNetworkElement_btn.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    <ImageBrush  x:Key="solveRoute" ImageSource="/icons/solve_btn.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    <ImageBrush  x:Key="solvePremiumRoute" ImageSource="/icons/solvePremium_btn.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    <ImageBrush  x:Key="RouteDirections" ImageSource="/icons/directions_btn.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    <ImageBrush  x:Key="AddTrafficLayer" ImageSource="/icons/AddTrafficLayer.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="cmButton">
        <MenuItem Name ="Draw_Sketch" Header="Draw Sketch" Click="btn_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Name ="Save_Sketch" Header="Save Sketch" Click="btn_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Name ="Delete_Sketch" Header="Delete Sketch" Click="btn_Click" IsEnabled="True"/>
        <MenuItem Name ="Remove_Selected_Vertex" Header="Remove Selected Vertex" Click="btn_Click" IsEnabled="True"/>
        <MenuItem Name ="Cancel" Header="Cancel" Click="btn_Click" IsEnabled="True"/>
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Address Geocoding" Click="btn_Click" IsEnabled="True"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="treeViewMenu">
        <MenuItem Name ="Delete_TreeViewElement" Header="Delete" Click="btn_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Name ="Delete_All_TreeViewElements" Header="Delete All" Click="btn_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Name ="Open_Attribute_Table" Header="Open_Attribute_Table" Click="btn_Click" IsEnabled="True"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="5,25,0,20" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="155">

            <!-- hieracical binding -->
            <TextBlock Text="Hierarchical root binding}" Foreground="Red" Margin="10,20,0,0"/>
            <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding LayersPool}" Margin="10" Height="200">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding LayersPool}" DataType="{x:Type local:Layer_Properties}">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding routeName}"/>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

i ve made numerous attempts to make it work but i cannot find a solution. What i want to achieve is create a treeview as follows:

```
Route_1
  Stops
    Stop1
    Stop2
    Stop3
  Polyline Barriers
    Barrier 1
Route_2
  Stops
    Stop1
    Stop2
  Polyline Barriers
    Barrier 1
    Barrier2
```

Edit I suspect there might be an issue with binding since LayersPool observablecollection is a mapviewmodel collection. Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand how `TreeView` binding works.

You can have a look here: [wpf treeview binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295644/wpf-treeview-binding) and also here: https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/treeview-data-binding-multiple-templates/

Generally speaking, if each `TreeViewItem` ViewModel needs to do something specific (for example once the user click on it, then you need to create your own ViewModel specific class for each `TreeViewItem`.

You might create an `AbstractViewModel` as a base class for every `TreeViewItem` ViewModel that contains basically 2 properties.

1. `Children` binded to `ItemsSource` in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` that contains an `ObservableCollection` of current treeviewitem's leaves
2. `Name` binded to your `Text` property of the `TextBlock` you placed in your `DataTemplate` to show the treeview item text.

Comment: yes i understand studying is everything but  i spent much time trying to find a solution and i cannot understand why the above code doesnt work. it cant be so difficult to bind a list of object to a treeview.